# validating haskell-platform compiled from source?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, haskell-platform

Is there a recommended way to validate Haskell Platform built from source?

I do see a `test` target in the [GHC `Makefile`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/Makefile),
but there doesn't seem to be test section in the [`platform.sh` script](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/blob/master/platform.sh).

Comment: You might try asking the [haskell-platform mailing list](http://projects.haskell.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/haskell-platform)

Comment: The GHC validation code is intended to support GHC development, not to check an installation. Validation builds run as part of the continuous integration process to ensure that modifications to the compiler and base libraries don't break things.

Answer (score 1):

The HP built from source uses a GHC tarball, so that tarball is ideally already validated.

There's no particular validation for the platform itself that is scriptable, as what is built is an installer.

Typically people building the installer fire up a virtual target system and attempt to install something like `pandoc` that pulls in a large enough chunk of hackage to give the entire system a workout...